# Analysing serial dependence in binary sequences

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, binary-data, independence

Suppose, I have a generator of a binary time series $x_t$. The generator produces a $1$ with probability $q$, except when there was a previous trial and the previous trial was a $1$: in this case the generator slightly increases the probability of a $1$ by $c$, i.e. the probability now is $q+c$.

Now, as a mere observer of such a time series, do I have any chance to proof, that $x_{t-1}=1$ increases the chance for a $1$ at time point $t$? Can I quantify by how much, i.e. $c$? Can I dissociate this from a generator, which instead increases the chance of a $0$ following a $0$? Can I reconstruct $q$?

Comment: Could you clarify the statement "the occurrence of a $1$ at time point $t$ increases the chance of a $1$ at time point $t+1$"? Increases relative to what?

Comment: Relative to q, which is the natural occurrence probability of a 1 in the absence of any history. I slightly modified the text now and hope it became more clear.